# Android Apache Codecs Base64 Error

Tags: java, encryption, base64, apache-commons

I'm trying to implement a more advanced password hashing algorithm (PBKDF2) that uses the Base64 class that is found in the java util library, but since this class is outdated I need to get the Apache Codecs library that supports the updated Base64 class. The amazing thing is that on a normal java class this works flawlessly, but when I use the same piece of code in an android activity it gives me an error saying that the method that I'm trying to call from Base64 does not exist!

I think the problem here is that in the activity, the Base64 is called from the util library that has the outdated version of Base64.
Here is an example of the code.

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Password {
    // The higher the number of iterations the more 
    // expensive computing the hash is for us and
    // also for an attacker.
    private final int iterations = 20 * 1000;
    private final int saltLen = 32;
    private final int desiredKeyLen = 256;

    /**
     * Computes a salted PBKDF2 hash of given plaintext password
     * suitable for storing in a database.
     * Empty passwords are not supported.
     */
    public String getSaltedHash(String password) throws Exception {
        byte[] salt = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").generateSeed(saltLen);
        // store the salt with the password
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(salt) + "$" + hash(password, salt);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether given plaintext password corresponds
     * to a stored salted hash of the password.
     */
    public boolean check(String password, String stored) throws Exception {
        String[] saltAndPass = stored.split("\\$");
        if (saltAndPass.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The stored password have the form 'salt$hash'");
        }
        String hashOfInput = hash(password, Base64.decodeBase64(saltAndPass[0]));
        return hashOfInput.equals(saltAndPass[1]);
    }

    // using PBKDF2 from Sun, an alternative is https://github.com/wg/scrypt
    // cf. http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2012/03/dont-use-bcrypt.html
    private String hash(String password, byte[] salt) throws Exception {
        if (password == null || password.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty passwords are not supported.");
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        SecretKey key = f.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(
                password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, desiredKeyLen)
        );
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Password passwordHash = new Password();
        String password = passwordHash.getSaltedHash("password");
        String password2 = passwordHash.getSaltedHash("password");
        System.out.println("P1-HASH: " + password);
        System.out.println("P2-HASH: " + password2);

        System.out.println(passwordHash.check("password", password2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you use the java Base64 class, so your description doesn't make sense. Also, you don't seem to have any question in here.

Comment: Base64 class was used 3 times in this code. 

The problem is with the "encodeBase64String" method, and I guess with the method to decode as well. The question can be elaborated from the explanation above.

Comment: The java util class is in the java.util package. It's not used anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The method seems to be called [`encodeToString`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.html#encodeToString-byte:A-). I really don't know where you found your particular method, but it isn't documented; I think you were just referring to the wrong class.

Comment: Apache is pretty crappy. By now Java has it's own Base64 class that certainly hasn't been deprecated. I'm not sure about the Android support, however.

Comment: The problem here is with encodeToString, in java.util.Base64 this method simply does not exist. But in the library "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BaseNCodec" exists, so theoretically I should be able to call the methods found in Base64 from the Apache library, but in practice I get a method does not exist exception :)

Comment: I don't know what the heck you are talking about. The method you listed doesn't exist, the one I listed does exist. What do you mean with "call the methods found in Base64 **from** the Apache library? Please tell me you are using a modern IDE to develop.

Comment: I use the latest android studio. This is a conflict between the two libraries with the same class Base64 (java.util.Base64 and apache.commons.codec.Base64)

Comment: `java.util.Base64` is *not* in the default classpath; so unless you explicitly import it you should not have any trouble. If you somehow require both then you should import neither or only one and then use the full classname *including* package. That way it is impossible to have a conflict.